# I get stackoverflowerror in some widgets and I don,t know why and what is this error

Tags: flutter, dart

**My code**

```
     class Userhomescreen extends StatefulWidget {
      final Size size;
 

     final String userid;

  final Users userdata;
  Userhomescreen({
    @required this.size,
    @required this.userid,
    @required this.userdata,
  });

  @override
  _UserhomescreenState createState() => _UserhomescreenState();
}

class _UserhomescreenState extends State<Userhomescreen> {
  var productsdata;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Database().getproducts().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        productsdata = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Userdrawer(size: widget.size, userdata: widget.userdata),
      appBar: Myappbar(
        size: widget.size,
        title: 'Fly buy',
        ishome: true,
        productsdata: productsdata,
        userid: widget.userid,
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: widget.size.width,
        height: widget.size.height,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Showmybanner(size: widget.size),
                if (productsdata == null) Container(
                        width: widget.size.width,
                        height: widget.size.height * 0.6,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
                            Data().colorslist['black'],
                          ),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                      ) else if(productsdata.runtimeType == String) 
                         Container(
                            width: widget.size.width,
                            height: widget.size.height * 0.6,
                            child: Text(productsdata.toString()),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                          )
                        else Column(
                            children: [
                              Categoryrow(
                                size: widget.size,
                                productsdata: productsdata,
                                userid: widget.userid,
                              ),
                              Seeall(
                                  size: widget.size, productlist: productsdata),
                              Appdivider(size: widget.size),
                              Hometext(
                                size: widget.size,
                                text: 'Top Products',
                                islogin: false,
                              ),
                              Topproducts(
                                size: widget.size,
                                productlist: productsdata,
                                userid: widget.userid,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**The Error I get **

Stack Overflow
The relevant error-causing widget was
Userhomescreen
lib\screens\whole_home_screen.dart:23
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Stack Overflow
The relevant error-causing widget was
Myappbar
lib\…\user_home_screen\user_screen.dart:41
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Stack Overflow
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
lib\…\user_home_screen\user_screen.dart:51
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Answer (score 0):

wrap `column` children with `Expanded` widgets.

```
column(
children : [
  Expanded(
    child : ... ), 
  Expanded(
    child : ... ),
  ...],
 )
```

Comment: it doesn't work it is giving me same issue